# Cannot translate specific characters with tr utility

Tags: linux, shell

Suppose I have a file named *doc* with content:

```
{}
[]
```

Now I want to translate all the '{' and '[' into '(' and '}' and ']' into ')'. So far, I can translate '{}' and '[' correctly, but I can't translate ']', using this shell command:

```
cat doc | tr [\[] [\(] | tr [\{] [\(] | tr [\}] [\)] | tr [\]] [\)] | cat
```

The output is:

```
()
(]
```

So far, it can translate other character, except for ']'. Do you know why?

This is a shell exercise, which asks to translate all '{}' and '[]' in a .c file into '()'. I just want to simply it here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one example that works fine:

```
echo '{}' |tr '\{\}' '\[\]'
```

> OUTPUT: []

Here's another example:

```
 echo '}' | tr \} \]
```

> OUTPUT: ]

Comment: Thanks. This was useful. It is shorter and easier to manage. However, I still don't understand why the last character ']' can't be translated into ')'.

Comment: In your second example, when I tried echo ] | tr \] \) , it works (great) but why not the one in the square bracket of regular expression: echo ] | tr [\]] [\)]

Answer (score 3):

`tr` just takes character sets and ranges - you don't need to surround them with `[]` like regular expression ranges.  You can do all your translations with a single command:

```
echo 'hello [ world }' | tr '[]{}' '()()'
```